# Factory reset disabled by server policy

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, lg, hard-reset

My phone (LGL15G running 4.4.2) has been behaving suspiciously, and since it is relatively new and I do not have any important data on it, I thought it would be best to wipe it.

When I select settings > backup & reset, the factory data reset option is greyed out, with the sub-heading reading: "factory data reset is disabled by server policy".

I unchecked my backup provider (Google) on the same screen (backup & reset), and the factory reset option is still greyed out with the same message. How do I get it to allow me to reset?

Comment: Check Settings > Security > Device Admins, See if something else is keeping it from letting you reset it. Is this device, a work device? Cause some companies can set up security policies to prevent people wiping the phone to get around certain locks and etc.

Answer (score 3):

If you cannot factory reset from  Android due to  a server policy, you can do a hard reboot via the recovery mode. From [LG's website](http://www.lg.com/us/mobile-phones/VS410PP/Userguide/007.html)<sup>1</sup>:

> 5. Using the hard reset
>
>    If you cannot recall your unlock pattern, PIN, or password, you need to perform a hard reset to access your phone.
>
>    When the phone is turned off, press and hold the Home Key  + Volume Down Key  +Power/Lock Key . When the screen shows the LG logo, release thePower/Lock Key .
>
>    When the screen displays an Android robot animation, release the other keys.
>
>    Leave your phone for at least a minute while it performs the hard reset, then your phone will reboot.

That should bypass any policy. Of course,  all the user data will be wiped.

---

<sub>1: The link is dead now. Gives error 404.</sub>